# Python Complicated Query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this models as following:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class UserPreference(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    fruit = models.MantToManyField(Fruit)
    vegetable = models.MantToManyField(Vegetable)

class RestaurantPreference(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant, on_delete=CASCADE)
    fruit = models.MantToManyField(Fruit)
    vegetable = models.MantToManyField(Vegetable)
```

how can i query in restaurant model using Preferences tables

for example I need to get resturants that has same preference for spec user?

please any one has an idea help me

Many Thanks

Comment: my guess is this is flask and sqlalchemy?

Comment: no it's django and django rest framework , but it doesn't matter.

I need to create function at the end print on console the result

BTW I edited tags for question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting user preference by querying with the user you will get the corresponding user's preference and the query would be like

```
user_preference = UserPreference.objects.get(user=user)
fruits = user_preference.fruit.all() # user's fruit preferences
vegetables = user_preference.vegetable.all() # user's vegetable preferences
```

Now you got all the fruits and vegetable preferences of the user. From this, you can query the restaurant preferences using django ORM

```
restaurant_preferences = RestaurantPreference.objects.filter(fruit__in=fruits, vegetable__in=vegetables)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use below code

```
user = UserPreference.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
vegetables = user.vegetable.all() #all vegetable
restaurant = RestaurantPreference.objects.filter(vegetable__in=vegetables)
```